# Two urns and ball swapping $k$ times successively

Tags: probability

In the beginning urn-1 contains $a$ white balls and $n-a$ black balls and urn-2 contains $b$ white balls and $m-b$ black balls. In one swap we randomly transfer one ball from urn-1 to urn-2 then one ball from urn-2 to urn-1. After $k$ successive swapping a ball is drawn randomly from urn-1, find the probability that it will be a white ball.

My working:

Let $P_i(r)=$ probability of getting a white ball from $i^{th}$ bag after $r$ swapping.

$\implies P_1(r+1)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{1}{n(m+1)}\right)P_1(r)+\frac{m}{n(m+1)}P_2(r)$

And
$P_2(r+1)=\frac{1}{m+1}P_1(r)+\frac{m}{m+1}P_2(r)$

$\implies\begin{pmatrix} P_1(r+1)\\ P_2(r+1)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{m}{n(m+1)}&\frac{m}{n(m+1)}\\ \frac{1}{m+1}&\frac{m}{m+1}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} P_1(r)\\ P_2(r)\end{pmatrix} $

$\implies\begin{pmatrix} P_1(k)\\ P_2(k)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{m}{n(m+1)}&\frac{m}{n(m+1)}\\ \frac{1}{m+1}&\frac{m}{m+1}\end{pmatrix} ^k\begin{pmatrix} \frac an\\ \frac bm\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: I'm not sure how much difference it makes, but during the swap, is the ball from urn 1 added to urn 2 before or after the ball is chosen from urn 2?

Comment: First we add a ball in urn-2 from urn-1 then we select a ball out of $m+1$ balls  in urn-2 and transfer it to urn -1 this is called 1 swapping

Comment: Have you tested the result numerically? The approach doesn't look quite right to me; the process might be better modelled as Markov? I can't see how you've incorporated the facts that an urn could at some point have no white balls, or only white balls, or how the cases where $a+b>n$ and $a+b\le n$ are handled, though this might just be because you haven't put any notes about your working in. By the way, I assume the top right entry of your matrix should be $\frac{m}{\color{Red}{n}(m+1)}$, is that right?

Comment: Just to expand on the Markov idea, you can keep track of the whole system by following the number of white balls in urn 1 after each complete swap. Say $a+b=W$; if after swap $i$ there are $a_i$ white balls in urn 1, then there are $n-a_i$ black balls in urn 1, $W-a_i$ white balls in urn 2 etc. If $n>W$, the states are $\{0,1,\ldots,W\}$ (because all white balls could be in urn 1). If $n\le W$, the states are $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ (because we can't have more than $n$ balls in urn 1). This is the clearest way to picture the system for me, but there are probably better ways.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Your method will work, but it is going to be a sparse transition matrix, (the number of white balls in urn 1 can only change by $+1,0,-1$ each time) so an efficient method may be able to take advantage of that.